# wire bends in eagle

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I am trying to do my first pcb design, using the freeware version of eagle 6.5. I will be making a single layer board using toner transfer.

I did the routing of all the tracks, but didnt know better and used 90 degree angles. How do I change the existing tracks to use 45 degree bends without un-routing all the tracks, couldnt find an option in change menu.

Also, whats the best track width and track spacings for home made pcbs. current  capability is not much of a concern. I am currently using 24mils for the track width, and whatever is set as default for track spacings.

I am using a couple of sot23 packages in this, hope home made pcbs can handle it. I am using these in mirrored mode to keep it on bottom layer.

Comment: You should consider splitting this into two questions, one about Eagle and one about home made PCBs (describing the technique you plan on using).

Comment: Honestly, don't be afraid to rip up all of the routes and start over. It's just part of laying out a good PCB sometimes. You have to be willing to let go of a bad design, even if you spent hours on it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Eagle can not 'pull corners' like Allegro or others can. You have to use *Miter* command to get fixed-length chamfers and then adjust them manually.

Width of 24 mil with spacing of 16 mil is comfortable and probably the thickest possible before toner coverage starts to be a problem (large black areas do not turn out well on laser printers).

Comment: Actually, it can. The "split" command can be used to create new corners in an existing trace, and right-clicking the mouse while doing this allows you to cycle among the various corner types on the fly.

Comment: thanx, I will try to use these numbers. did unrip all tracks and redid with the bend styles.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, with *split* it is also possible, but what I meant is that you can not drag a \$90^\circ\$ corner to create two \$45^\circ\$ corners.